# Changing swagger baseurl from one google project to other automatically

Tags: azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, swagger-2.0, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a project on dev environemnt on google project. Say swagger ui with url app.endpoints.DEV.goog (baseurl) and I want to deploy it to QA with app.endpoints.QA.goog , Is there a way of doing this automatically by replacing DEV to QA during build process via vsts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pre-defined variable **`$(Release.EnvironmentName)`** to get each environment name separately.

Assume there are two environments (`DEV` and `QA`) in your release definition, then you can use `app.endpoints.$(Release.EnvironmentName).goog` for each environment:

- In `DEV` environment, the value of the `app.endpoints.$(Release.EnvironmentName).goog` will be `app.endpoints.DEV.goog`;
- In `QA` environment, the value of the `app.endpoints.$(Release.EnvironmentName).goog` will be `app.endpoints.QA.goog`.